# What is best & Secure timer for online test application in asp.net C# Ajax timer or Jquery Timer?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, timer

I am creating a new application in asp.net 4.0 which contains an online test module, and the application is supposed to handle 10-20k students at a time. Now my confusion is what should i use here, which should be:

1. Secure , I don't want kids to turn off javascript in browser and get unlimited time for test.
2. Which should not overhead the network traffic.
3. Which have a pause/start function with try limits.
4. Should fire the needed function on server side after time is complete (e.g. redirect to another page via c# function)

Any help and example code is appreciated.

Regards

Alok Sharma

FYI: I am not experienced with jquery.

Answer (score 2):

If the security of timer is critical you should not fully rely on javascript code. I would recommend to keep the time when test is started for a specific user on both sides, server and client. Then implement javascript timer which periodically synchronizes with web server. When user completes the test and sends results to the server you should check if the timeout is elapsed on server side.

In additional I would add a logic in order to ban the possibility to open the page and start test without javascript enabled.

Comment: thanks i had the similar idea on this but you have one extra point in it :)

Comment: hi i have done what you said but now their is a issue in this approach, as i have place ajax timer to async update the label ;the page refreshes and thus the jquery timer of client side resets or fail ; what to do

Comment: @Alok. Could you describe the problem more detailed? Do you use sync page updates?

Comment: thanx for reply but i got it, the problem was in timer plugin; i am searching for a new one can you help?

Comment: @Alok The simplest timer whould be javascript `setTimeout` function. If it is not enough for, please explain which functionality you expect from the timer.

Comment: i am trying to find a timer which does count or precisely a stop watch

Comment: But as we discussed - you won't fnd such JS timer because it is a complex solution based on server and client code.